# How to grab data into RShiny from excel based on cell color properties

Tags: r, excel

We want to upload the file in shiny
But read only values based on cell color properties
(Cell background = white -> read value
else ignore)
How can we do it ?

Please find the template to read excel below
and screenshot of an excel :

[image]

```r
#install.packages("readxl")
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Use readxl"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        
        req(input$file1)
        
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with [tag:shiny]. For simplicity, please simplify this question to just the relevant component: reading the cell properties of an Excel worksheet. (I'm fairly confident that `readxl` will not support that functionality, so you may need to try `openxlsx` or some other package. I don't know what if any package supports it.)

Comment: FYI, for stack [markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), code block "fences" (`\`\`\``) need to be on lines of their own, optionally the opening fence may contain a language "hint". [edit] your question to see my suggested edits to improve the formatting (and fixing the image).